# Change account name in application

Tags: google-plus

I have an application with possibility of sign in using G+. I have access to this application settings. As example I'll show same page for Stack Overflow so you will understand what I'm talking about.

Here is page:

[image: stack exchange]

You can see name Stack Exchange with link. Where in settings of application I can change this name?

Comment: google cloud console

Comment: thank you Zig. I have renamed project in Google Cloud Console but name in sign in dialog was not changes. Probably something else should be changed

Comment: never said to rename the project. look well in there in the api section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is place where information shown as name stored:

> Google Cloud Console → API manager → Credentials → OAuth consent screen → Product name shown to users field.